# Annapurna Tilicho Lake without camping?

Tags: accommodation, trekking, nepal

The [Tilicho Lake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilicho_Lake) is a side trek in the [Annapurna circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annapurna). Usually, the Annapurna circuit is traveled from guesthouse to guesthouse, without outdoor camping.

Is it possible to visit the Tilicho Lake without outdoors camping? I don't want to carry a tent during 18 days just for a single night use.

[image]

[Image credit-Wikimedia commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tilicho_Lake.jpg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just came back from my trekking vacation in Nepal.

It's possible (and simple) to get to the lake without camping, using local guesthouses. It requires no special means like helicopters, and it even helps with acclimatization before the [Thorung La Pass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorong_La).

Answer (score 5):

Answering from search results since this question has gone unanswered for so long. It seems that most organised tours are 18-20 day trekking tours, and yes, there are options to stay in guest houses as [this itinerary](http://brothersadventures.com/nepal/nepal-adventure-treks/nepal-tilicho-lake-trek.html) seems to suggest. You could also see it without trekking on helicopter tours of the region ([such as this one](http://www.kailashhelicoptertours.com/holy_tilicho_lake.php), same details show up on multiple sites in searches and even have the same phone number listed so I'm guessing it's just one operator on the ground); might be prohibitively expensive compared to a trek though.